# How to find the value of auto generated ID?

Tags: angular

In my angular program, I have a table with a blank row, `newRow`, at the bottom of my table. I can enter values into all of the columns in the new row and press a submit button which will add the row to the table and clear out the new row so there's always one at the bottom. Whenever it's added to the database, a random key number is generated, such as 180316. I want to be able to delete that row after entering it, so how do I find out what the new key number that has been generated is?

I've tried this:

```
newRowID: number = 0;
```

and putting this inside the `saveNewRow` function:

```
    this.newRowID = this.ptoData.length - 1;
    this.newRow.ID = this.ptoData[this.newRowID].ID;
```

but it didn't work. How would I go about finding what the new key number that has been generated is?

Here's my `saveNewRow` function:

```
saveNewRow(): void {
    this.ptoDataService.save({
        ID: 0,
        EmpKey: this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey,
        type: this.selectedType,
        date: this.newRow.date,
        fullhalf: this.newRow.fullhalf,
        hours: this.newRow.hours,
        scheduled: this.newRow.scheduled,
        notes: this.newRow.notes,
        inPR: (this.newRow.inPR ? true : false),
        prDate: this.newRow.prDate
    })
    this.ptoData.push({
        ID: 0,
        EmpKey: this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey,
        type: this.selectedType,
        date: this.newRow.date,
        fullhalf: this.newRow.fullhalf,
        hours: this.newRow.hours,
        scheduled: this.newRow.scheduled,
        notes: this.newRow.notes,
        inPR: (this.newRow.inPR ? true : false),
        prDate: this.newRow.prDate
    })
    this.updateTotals();
    this.newRow = new PTOData();
}
```

here's the `save` function called inside that:

```
save(pto: PTOData): Promise<PTOData> {
    return this.http
        .put(this.ptoDateUrl + '/' + pto.ID, pto, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as PTOData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

then, here's the delete function:

```
deleteRow(currPTO: PTOData): void {
    this.ptodataService
        .delete(currPTO.ID)
        .then(() => {
            this.onDelete.emit(currPTO.ID);
        })
    this.rowSelected = null;
}
```

and here's the `delete` function that's called:

```
delete(ID: number): Promise<void> {
    return this.http.delete(this.ptoDateUrl + '?ID=' + ID)
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => null)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your save is returning the updated object, which I assume has the key value, in your code here:

```
save(pto: PTOData): Promise<PTOData> {
    return this.http
        .put(this.ptoDateUrl + '/' + pto.ID, pto, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as PTOData)  <-- HERE
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When you call this method, you need to access that returned data.

I use Observables instead of promises, so I don't know what the syntax would be with promises. With Observables it is something like this:

```
     this.productService.saveProduct(p)
        .subscribe(
            (product: IProduct) => this.returnedProduct = product,
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
```

You'd need to change my product example to your PTOData.